# R:purrr Finding the list elements that contain named variables

Tags: r, list, reference, iteration, purrr

I have a character vector `nms` of variable names that all appear in at least one of several files. If a variable exists in more than one file, the values will be the same.

I have a named list `test_lst`  where the top-level  names are the names of the files. A sublist of the list includes a vector of the names of the variables in the file.

I would like to use purrr go through `test_lst` and find the first file that contains each of the variables, and return a named list where the names are the filenames and each element is a vector of the variables in `nms` that exist in that file. And I would like to index the sublist by name, not by position.

It seems like this should be easy, and I don’t know why I can not make it work.

Data:

```
test_lst <- list(ob1 = list(v1 = list(s1 = "X", s2 = paste0("A", 1:3)), v2 =  paste0("A", 4:8)), 
                 ob2 = list(v1 = list(s1 = "X", s2 = paste0("A", 9:11)), v2 =  paste0("A", 12:16)))

nms <- c (paste0("A", 1:2), paste0("A", 9:10))
```

Non-working code:

```
find_vars <- function(var_names, meta){
map_chr(meta, c("v1", "s2")) -> var_vecs
names(var_vecs)<- names(meta)   
map_chr(var_vecs, var_names %in% .) -> out
names(out) <- names(var_vecs)
out
}

find_vars(var_names = nms, meta = test_lst)
```

Desired output, a list:

```
$ob1
[1] "A1" "A2"
$ob2
[1] "A9"  "A10"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `modify_depth`

```
library(tidyverse)
modify_depth(test_lst, 2, ~ enframe(.x) %>%
          select(value) %>%
          unnest %>%
          filter(value %in% nms)) %>%
   flatten %>%
   keep(~ nrow(.x) > 0) %>% 
   map(~ .x %>%
          pull(value)) %>% 
   set_names(names(test_lst))
#$ob1
#[1] "A1" "A2"

#$ob2
#[1] "A9"  "A10"
```

---

Or we can `enframe` first and then loop through the 'value' column to subset the elements

```
enframe(test_lst) %>% 
     unnest %>% 
     mutate(value = map(value, ~ intersect(nms, unlist(.x))))  %>% 
     unnest %>%
     deframe %>%
     split(names(.))
```

---

Or using the same notation we used with `intersect` earlier

```
map(test_lst, ~ intersect(nms, unlist(.x)))
```

---

or another option is `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
melt(test_lst) %>%
     select(L1, value) %>%
     group_by(L1) %>% 
     filter(value %in% nms) %>% 
     {split(as.character(.$value), .$L1)}
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! Excellent answer.  I asked for an answer that used the purrr extraction functions, because this problem arose as part of my effort to understand purrr. But I am going to accept this answer anyway, both because of value of seeing three different ways to do this, and also because I had never used enframe or deframe either, and that seems like a lesson of comparable value. And I have another question posted that gets at the purrr extraction issues more directly.

Answer (score 2):

We can `unlist` all values of `test_lst` and find out common values using `intersect`

```
lapply(test_lst, function(x) intersect(unlist(x), nms))

#$ob1
#[1] "A1" "A2"

#$ob2
#[1] "A9"  "A10"
```

If you want to use `purrr`, we can change `lapply` to `map`

```
purrr::map(test_lst, ~intersect(unlist(.), nms))
```